# Reading DICOM 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70

Tags: dicom, medical, lossless

I have a problem when reading DICOM file. This is the format 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70(Process 14 with a first-order prediction (Selection Value 1). I write my own software.

Here is result of my work.

[image: CLICK]

I also give you a [.dcm file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bw5-VXnqutXBam93ZDFyUG15Z2s).

What can be wrong with it? Only RadiAnt Dicom Viewer open it corectly ( i didn't find any working software with source code ).
Have someone any tutorial about it? Any working code?

I'll be very grateful!
Thanks for help.

---

I show you how I it do:

```
//I have:
numCOL= imageWidth;
numROW= imageHeight;

dwCurrentBufferLength;//-> where I in file

//and other stuff...

//First i decode first row:
//[0][0]

DecodeFirstRow(curRowBuf,dwCurrentBufferLength);

//I calculate difrences
HuffDecode ( table , &val, dwCurrentBufferLength);

//and extend
HuffExtend(extend, val);

curRowBuf[0][curComp]=extend+(1<<(Pr-Pt-1));

//[1-n][0]
//... huff stuff
curRowBuf[col][curComp]=extend+curRowBuf[col-1][curComp];

//Then i put row to the vector:
for (col = 0; col < numCol; col++) 
{       
v=RowBuf[col][0]<<point_transform_parameter;                    
m_vOutputBuf.push_back(v);
}   

//Rest of columns
//[0][m]
curRowBuf[0][curComp]=extend+prevRowBuf[0][curComp];    


predictor = left =curRowBuf[leftcol][curComp];
//[1-n][m]
curRowBuf[col][curComp]=extend+predictor;
//and also put it to vector ^^
```

Where i must sub this 1000??

Comment: it's not clear of what's wrong, a dicom file you made or the program you wrote to read it?

Comment: It program wrong. Dicom File is corect

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have not accounted for the *Rescale Intercept*, tag (0028,1052) when calculating your HU values. According to the DICOM file, the intercept is -1000.

To get the appropriate HU values of your image, use this formula:

```
HU = rescale_slope * pixel_value + rescale_intercept
```

where *Rescale Intercept* is thus obtained from tag (0028,1052) and *Rescale Slope* from tag (0028,1053).

Comment: Thanks for answer but where it must be sub? I have deadline today :(

Comment: It is very difficult to tell from the code you have provided, but it is the values that _go into_ the JPEG compression that need to be modified. The `val` array, perhaps? If you are going to extend your application further, I **strongly** recommend that you start relying on a regular DICOM toolkit instead, for example the [OFFIS DCMTK Toolkit](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I see using gdcmviewer:

$ gdcmviewer 3DSlice1.dcm

[image]

[GDCM](http://gdcm.sf.net) is open source you could study it.